# How to calculate the safe AC frequency at high Voltages?

Tags: voltage, ac, frequency, electricity, arc

If someone wanted to build some kind of machine which produces HUGE and completely safe electric arcs, how would you calculate the frequency of the AC current in relation to Volt to make it safe? 
Why is it extremely dangerous to produce arcs in high voltages in DC (assuming the electricity flows through your body) but also relatively safe if it is done with AC (assuming you have adjusted the frequency of the circuit to make it safe)? I am very sorry if this question is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything in the internet.

Comment: Regarding safety of high AC vs DC: Humans act as capacitors and AC shorts a capacitor, so current can pass through them.

Comment: Why do you think any one frequency is safer than another? Also, look at the precautions taken by workers on high voltage AC power lines if you think AC is safe.

Comment: Depends on if he means painful or deadly. I'm sure the YouTuber ElectroBOOM has a few videos where he electrocutes his tongue with a frequency generator.

Comment: Skin effect is a major factor. I’ve had high voltage shocks at 600 kHz and received minor surface burns. Look up skin effect and note that skin, in this comment, doesn’t refer to human skin but how deep a high frequency ac current penetrates from a surface.

Comment: Define what you mean by "safe" and "completely safe". Also define what you mean by "arc", because it doesn't sound like you are actually talking about an actual arc all the time in your question. I assume your AC vs DC arc lethality is with regards to the self-extinguishing nature of AC arcs due to the zero cross.

Comment: @Barry, I think that the OP is asking about VHF or higher frequencies, not 60Hz.

Comment: Skin effect at radio frequencies will make it hard to pass significant current through the victim's heart, but that does not mean that a "huge" arc won't give them horrible RF burns.  https://hamradioschool.com/t0c07-rf-burn/

Comment: @tanto Let’s be extremely unambiguous when talking about electricity and safety. That ElectroBoom guy knows very well of what he’s doing due to his large background in electrical engineering... (though I do question whether he’s some type of masochist).

Comment: @Ozan, Could you be more precise about what is the kind of machine that you are talking ? Do you have some examples ? The answer will be more accurate to explain you why it is safer...  or not.

Answer (score 1):

Humans in shoes have about 1,000 picoFarad capacintace to Ground, thru the shoes.

C = Eo * Er * AREA/dISTANCE

C = 45PF/METER * Er * (10cm * 30cm) / 1cm * 1meter/100cm

C = 45e-12 * (Er = 5 for shoes) * 300cm * 1meter/100cm ~~~ 700 picoFarad

Now lets assume the frequency is 1MHz and the Voltage is 100,00 volts.

The displacement current, generated as electric fields change and charges rush around and back and forth to balance those fields, is

I = C * dV/dT

I = 700pF * [ 100,000 volts * d(1MHz)/dT  ]

I = 700pF * [100,000 * (2*pi * 1MHz)] = 700pF * 100,000 * 6.28e+6 radians/second

I = 700e-12 * 1e+5 * 6e+6 ~~~ 4,000 * 1e(-12 +5 +6) = 400 amps thru the point of entry of the arc, thru your body, and exiting your shoes.

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that at sufficiently high frequency, those typically used in Tesla Coils for instance, you don't tend to feel electric shocks, that doesn't mean the passage of current isn't causing you any damage.